# error 1004 when trying to delete blank rows in a table

Tags: excel, vba

i gave a table where I want to delete any rows without data... I have tried many options and spent ages on trying to figure this out myself...
The code is part of a much bigger sub but I hope someone can point me in the right direction.
when the code runs I get Error 1004 Method "delete" of object "range" failed....

thanks in advance!

```
Dim row As Range
With ws_IAD
lastrow = tbl_IAD.Range.Rows(tbl_IAD.Range.Rows.count).row

 With tbl_IAD.DataBodyRange
    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Rows.Delete
End With
End With
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)` doesn't return a contigous range - therefore you can't delete them this way.

There are two options.

- First one: if you have no data to the left or right of your listobject/table then the whole sheet row can be deleted
- Second one: checking table row by row if empty - and then delete the row of the table (this will be less performant if you have a huge table).

You can call either or these subs like this: `deleteEmptyRowsOfListobject tbl_IAD`

**Option 1** filters for all empty rows and then deletes the visible rows.

```vb
Public Sub deleteEmptyRows(lo As ListObject)

Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To lo.ListColumns.Count
    lo.Range.AutoFilter i, "="
Next

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
With lo.DataBodyRange
    On Error Resume Next 'in case there are no empty rows
        'this will delete the whole sheet row!!! -->
        'if there is content to the left or to the right of the listobject it will get deleted too!
        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
End With
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

lo.AutoFilter.ShowAllData

End Sub
```

**Option 2** uses worksheetfunction CountA to return number of non-empty cells in range.

```vb
Public Sub deleteEmptyRowsOfListobject(lo As ListObject)

Dim i As Long, lr As ListRow

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

With lo.ListRows
    For i = .Count To 1 Step -1
        Set lr = .Item(i)
        If WorksheetFunction.CountA(lr.Range) = 0 Then
            lr.Delete
        End If
    Next
End With

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```